# Вывести список таблиц базы mysql с количеством записей в таблице, дата первой записи, дата последней записи

Tags: php, mysql

В базе данных есть таблицы в которых есть поле дата для каждой записи, например:

```
Table1
ID        Time               Value
1  2017-07-04 03:59:39         65
2  2017-07-05 01:00:00        100
3  2017-07-05 10:20:03         20

Table2
ID        Time               Value
1  2016-07-01 02:20:07         33
2  2016-07-13 01:00:00          5
3  2016-07-22 10:20:03         80
и т.д...
```

Количество таблиц неизвестно, могут добавляться новые или удаляться.
Я знаю как вывести все таблицы с количеством записей например:

```
SELECT table_name, table_rows 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'myDataBase';
```

Вид будет такой:

```
table_name table_rows
Table1          3
Table2          3
```

...

А мне нужно чтобы вид был такой:

```
table_name table_rows     date_start            date_end
Table1          3     2017-07-04 03:59:39   2017-07-05 10:20:03
Table2          3     2016-07-01 02:20:07   2016-07-22 10:20:03
...
```

Надеюсь, что всё понятно объяснил. Для меня эта задача пока непосильная, хотел вывести на сайте данные из базы данных с помощью php скрипта. Буду благодарен за помощь, спасибо.

Comment: одним запросом это сделать нельзя. надо делать процедуру, которая для каждой записи из tables создаст в виде текста динамический запрос для получения нужных значений из конкретной таблицы и где то сохранит, например во временной таблице

Comment: Mike, спасибо за ответ друг!) Ну я в принципе так и думал, получить список из названий таблиц, записать в массив, потом в цикле из массива брать название таблицы, записать в переменную и делать запросы для каждой таблицы. Готовлюсь морально это сделать, спасибо еще раз)

Comment: Уже представляю себе, какой трактор получится при большом количестве таблиц в базе)))

Comment: Судя по комменту, Вы собрались делать это на клиенте.. не надо. Делайте это в хранимой процедуре на сервере. Навскидку в процедуре будет  12-13 строк - не такой уж и "трактор".

Comment: Если эту информацию надо часто выводить, то стоит сделать свою таблицу, в которую ее сохранять. и придумать метод обновления данных в ней. можно просто время от времени, если текущие актуальные данные не критичны. Или создавать на все таблицы триггера, которые будут обновлять в этой сводной таблице информацию о себе при изменениях. Или как то ориентироваться на table_rows что бы решать когда обновлять инфу. А то куча `select min(dt), max(dt) from tab` тормозить будет знатно ...

Comment: Спасибо Akina, да, я и собирался написать обработчик на php, а клиенту выдать уже готовую таблицу.

Comment: @Romchik Вообще Akina имел ввиду другое, сделать процедуру в самой БД через `create procedure` которая целиком все посчитает и отдаст. хотя в данном конкретном случае я особой разницы не вижу в php это делать или целиком в БД

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем всем спасибо ребята за поддержку! Не знаю, хорошо это или нет, программирую первый раз, но сгородил вот такую конструкцию:

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect(localhost, root, passw, baza) 
    or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link));

$query ="SHOW TABLES FROM baza;";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link));
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);//количество таблиц в базе

  for ($i = 0 ; $i < $rows ; ++$i)
    {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
        $arr[] = "$row[0]";//массив с названиями таблиц в базе

        $query1 ="SELECT `Timestamp` FROM `{$arr[$i]}` ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1;";
        $result1 = mysqli_query($link, $query1) or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link));
        $row1 = mysqli_fetch_row($result1);
        $arr1[] = "$row1[0]";//массив с первыми датами для каждой таблицы

        $query2 ="SELECT `Timestamp` FROM `{$arr[$i]}` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;";
        $result2 = mysqli_query($link, $query2) or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link));
        $row2 = mysqli_fetch_row($result2);
        $arr2[] = "$row2[0]";//массив с последними датами для каждой таблицы

        echo "<p>$arr[$i] $arr1[$i] $arr2[$i]</p>";}   

mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_free_result($result1);
mysqli_free_result($result2);

mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Если честно, то не захотел лезть в саму базу данных и создавать там процедуры, подумал, что может забуду или кто-то удалит, а так всё лежит в php файле...
У меня пока работает, может кому пригодится ;)